# "Save Edits" button grays out after a moment when editing a deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, deleted-questions

(**EDIT**: Removed the confusion about whether deleted questions are editable, and added some details)

When I start editing a deleted question, after about a minute the "Save Edits" button dynamically grays out. The page shifts down, and it looks like it's made space for an orange information bar along the top (like the "this is your first time here" alert), only nothing is displayed:

[image: Screenshot of the above]

This only happens after I've started editing (just adding a space at the end of the post is sufficient); if I sit on the page and don't change the post text the button stays enabled. If I submit changes before the button grays out everything works fine. It looks like the button is disabled after the browser tries to post to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/56804/edit-activity-heartbeat`

I'm using Firefox 3.6.3 on Linux, but this also happens using Chromium

Comment: You put the same hypertext for both links.

Comment: @Lance Oh, so I did; now I can't find the question anymore and the revision doesn't show up in my [activity history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/309308?tab=activity#tab-top), which confuses me greatly

Comment: Confusion gone, it turns out edits to deleted questions never show up there; not sure if that's a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56813/edits-of-deleted-questions-dont-appear-in-a-users-activity-history) or not. Anyway, I rewrote the question to give more information and hopefully be less confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the javascript around these notifications - a fix will be pushed to production this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted posts can be edited if you have enough rep, and I've just tried it and didn't see the *Save Edits* button greyed out, so it seems like that is the bug...