# “Save Edits” button grays out after a moment when editing a deleted question, part 2

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, deleted-questions

I filed a bug last month that was just fixed a couple days ago about [editing deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/save-edits-button-grays-out-after-a-moment-when-editing-a-deleted-question). The problem was after about a minute of editing the save button would be disable and a blank space would appear where an information bar should go. Jarrod [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/save-edits-button-grays-out-after-a-moment-when-editing-a-deleted-question/60757#60757) it was fixed, but it looks like all that was fixed was the information bar; it now shows:

[image: This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed]

That's the opposite of what perbert said in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/save-edits-button-grays-out-after-a-moment-when-editing-a-deleted-question/56806#56806):

> Deleted posts can be edited if you have enough rep

And indeed, just as in the other bug report, as long as I finish my edit and hit save before the button is disabled and that bar comes up, the edit is successful

If it's true that no more edits are allowed on deleted questions, this is a loophole to get around that, but I think it's sane to allow 10k users to edit deleted posts if they want. I often clean up a closed post and vote to reopen it, and on occasion I've cleaned up a deleted post and voted to undelete it; there doesn't seem to be any reason why I'd be allowed to do the former but not the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10k+ rep users will no longer be stopped from editing deleted posts.

This change will be pushed to all sites this evening.