# Please don't block a user from editing a deleted post if the edit is initiated post-deletion

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

In a similar vein as to the warnings about answering a closed question or revising a question when someone has posted an edit, there is a warning you get if you try to edit a question that has been deleted.

[image: This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed]

When this pops up, the "save edits" button is disabled and it prevents you from submitting an edit.

This is despite the fact that if you have 10k reputation or a ♦, you are able to edit these posts. In fact, this can actually show up if you start an edit *while the post is already deleted*. I had to redo a spam clearance edit on a recently deleted spam post (♦ bypasses the locked status, as well).

This was noted as a [Javascript error from a report in July 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/save-edits-button-grays-out-after-a-moment-when-editing-a-deleted-question), and then supposedly fixed again after a [second report in August 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61110/save-edits-button-grays-out-after-a-moment-when-editing-a-deleted-question-pa), but the problem still seems live. Further research shows that it only occurs if the post is *locked* and deleted, which leads me to two changes that would be nice.

- If the user is a ♦, they can edit locked posts, and should not run into this. Either don't disable anything at all, or at least only restrict the disabling to if the deletion happens *after* the ♦ starts editing.
- For non-♦ users, namely 10k users who normally can edit deleted posts, the banner should be changed to say "This post has been **locked** - no more edits are allowed". Otherwise, the current banner is inaccurate, to say the least.

---

Comment: +1 I'd prefer to just not see the warning at all.

Comment: I have found an issue with *locked and deleted* posts, but this shouldn't happen on deleted posts that are *not* locked. Are you sure you've seen this on a non-locked post?

Comment: @balpha I'm willing to test (and concede, if tests show such), but if that is the case then the message should be revised, and it still shouldn't lock out on a diamond.

Comment: Yes, that's a plain old bug and will be fixed -- just making sure I'm not missing anything else.

Comment: @balpha Well, it's been hours of testing in two separate browsers, and I think I can say that, yeah, it seems to only show up on locked/deleted posts. I'll revise this report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were several issues with checking the edit permission during the heartbeat (that's what we call the poll to the server, checking e.g. for recent deletions or edits). The heartbeat is highly optimized (it gets called a lot), which is why it can't go through the regular permissions validation pipeline. These issues are fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

There's not much more frustrating than spending a lot of time on an edit, then have it thrown away by the system.  I think checking that your rep level is sufficient is at least a start, but why not let those less than 10k do their edit, but have it need to be approved just like the normal edit preview process (except only 10ks could see and approve it)?